# Show that, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = y$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^2 = y^2$

Tags: analysis

This question seems easy, but I can't figure it out anyway.

> Show that, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = y$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n^2 = y^2$.
>
> Hint:
>
> • $x_n^2 − y^2 = (x_n − y)(x_n + y)$,
>
> • for any numbers $a$, $b$, $|ab| = |a| |b|$ and $|a + b| ≤ |a| + |b|$,
>
> • if $x_n\to y$ then eventually, $|x_n| ≤ |y| + 1$.
>
> Give a full proof: start with arbitrary bigger than zero, then find $N$ such that . . . .

The question shows above, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have an idea
if we have (Xn-Y)^2 = Xn^2 - 2XnY + Y^2
then (Xn-Y)^2 = Xn^2 - 2Y^2 + Y^2 = Xn^2 -Y^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More hints: let $\varepsilon >0$. You have to show, that $|x_n^2 - y^2|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N(\varepsilon)$. Therefore estimate $|x_n^2 - y^2|$ with the three given hints. I can not give you more hints because this would already solve the problem (and that is your job).

Answer (score 0):

What does the subscript denote? We could just raise both sides to the power of $2$ and see that if $x = y$, then $x^2 = y^2$.

Comment: $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence.  The question about why we can pass a limit through the function $f(x) = x^2$ from first principles (i.e. without first proving that limits pass through continuous functions).  Your approach does not work here.